# Azure SQL Build, Release and Deploy, DACPAC/Artifacts needs to Build.profile.xml

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, dacpac

I can easily publish my SQL DB in Visual studio using a Build.Profile.xml. But when I am doing a build/Release in Azure, I cannot see this xml in the Artifacts. I need to configure the Release Definition to use this file in my publish, but I cannot see this file in the artifacts of the build and inside the DACPAC file. I already have the SQL deploy task in the Release definition, but I cannot see the Build Profile path because its not in the artifacts/DACPAC. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to change the file's properties in **Visual Studio** the value of **Copy to Output Directory** to either **Copy Always** or **Copy if Newer**.

Hope it helps!